# 'Collection' requires the types 'MyCollectionClass.Element' and 'Slice< MyCollectionClass>' be equivalent

Tags: swift

I am trying to make a custom collection type in Swift 4. I've implemented:
`startIndex`, `endIndex`, `index(after:)`, `subscript(Element)`, `subscript(Range<Element>)` and have assigned a type to `Element`. Why am I getting this error?

```
extension MyCollectionClass: Collection {
    public typealias Element = MyCollectionElement

    public var startIndex: Int {
        return _values.startIndex
    }

    public var endIndex: Int {
        return _values.endIndex
    }

    public func index(after: Index) -> Index {
        return _values.index(after: after)
    }

    public subscript(position: Index) -> Element {
        return _values[position]
    }

    public subscript(bounds: Range<Index>) -> SubSequence {
        return _values[bounds]
    }
}
```

> 'Collection' requires the types 'MyCollectionClass.Element' and 'Slice< MyCollectionClass>' be equivalent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a completely useless error message (which I would encourage you to [file a bug](https://bugs.swift.org) over) – the problem is twofold:

- You're confusing the compiler by interchangeably using `Int` and `Index`.
- You're referring to `SubSequence` without actually having satisfied that associated type.

You can solve both of these by just defining type aliases in order to explicitly satisfy both the `Index` and `SubSequence` associated types:

```
public class MyCollectionClass<MyCollectionElement> {
    var _values = [MyCollectionElement]()
}

extension MyCollectionClass: Collection {

    public typealias Element = MyCollectionElement
    public typealias Index = Int

    // as ArraySlice is Array's SubSequence type.
    public typealias SubSequence = ArraySlice<MyCollectionElement>

    public var startIndex: Index {
        return _values.startIndex
    }

    public var endIndex: Index {
        return _values.endIndex
    }

    public func index(after: Index) -> Index {
        return _values.index(after: after)
    }

    public subscript(position: Index) -> Element {
        return _values[position]
    }

    public subscript(bounds: Range<Index>) -> SubSequence {
        return _values[bounds]
    }
}
```

Although note that you don't have to implement the `subscript(bounds:)` requirement – `Collection` offers a default implementation for that, which simply returns a `Slice<Self>`.

Also, if possible, I would rename your (assumed) generic placeholder just to `Element`, and have the compiler infer that the placeholder satisfies the `Element` associated type from the subscript declaration:

```
public class MyCollectionClass<Element> {
    var _values = [Element]()
}

extension MyCollectionClass: Collection {

    public typealias Index = Int

    public var startIndex: Index {
        return _values.startIndex
    }

    public var endIndex: Index {
        return _values.endIndex
    }

    public func index(after: Index) -> Index {
        return _values.index(after: after)
    }

    public subscript(position: Index) -> Element {
        return _values[position]
    }
}
```